# How to combine Countif & UPPER functions in google sheet to count all matches?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I'm trying to find all matches regardless of capital or small letters by using this formula
`=countif(AllCases!A1:A100,UPPER"*ICU*")`

but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: You do not need `UPPER()`. Countif by default case insensative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use just:

```
=COUNTIF(AllCases!A1:A100; "*ICU*")
```